# Carry on with UI while waiting for WebClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I'm trying to get a progress bar to show the program is loading (using ProgressStyle.Marquee) while a WebClient object reads from a site. The problem is that upon clicking the button that begins the call, the entire UI freezes up. I've tried putting it in a BackgroundWorker doWork but that causes it to never get any data at all. I've also tried delegates and various Thread options but all seem to have the same issue.

I'm fairly new to C# and have mostly been trying results I've found on the web but none seem to solve my problem.

What I have:

```
private void getInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = false;
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead("URI here"));
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

My attempt with BackgroundWorker

```
private void getInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = false;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWord += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync("URI here");
    while (bw.IsBusy)
        ;
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = true;
}

private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(e.Argument);
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // Do stuff
    }        
}
```

Comment: Post your BackgroundWorker try, that's the normal way to do background work in Windows Forms.

Comment: Did you check your WebClient actually terminates reading the data? I.e. does "the UI freezes up" mean you have to wait some time, but sooner or later you get back to your app, or is it hanging up forever? In the latter case you have to find out how to signal that there is nothing left to read, before you can try to put the operation into a worker thread (which surely is a good idea in the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at my BackgroundWorker attempt I realised it was defeating the point of asynchronicity and the `getInfoButton_Click` method would be stalling (effectively freezing the UI) until it completed. Playing around with the BackgroundWorker some more I managed to get it to work:

```
private void getInfoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = false;
    BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
    bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
    bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    bw.RunWorkerAsync("URI Here");
}

void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(client.OpenRead(e.Argument));
        e.Result = reader;
}

void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    StreamReader reader = (StreamReader)e.Result;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
        // Do stuff
    }
    progressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
    getInfoButton.Enabled = true;
}
```